# Proper way to suppress a field from every element in a collection in python-eve

Tags: python, mongodb, eve

I would like to prevent a certain largish field in a collection of documents from being returned as part of the basic resource request in an eve app. What is the proper way of doing this? I was thinking of using an on_fetch hook but thought maybe there was some way of specifying this in the schema instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Projections](http://python-eve.org/features.html#projections) can also be used to [Limit the Fieldset Exposed by the API](http://python-eve.org/features.html#leveraging-projections-to-optimize-the-handling-of-media-files):

> When setting the datasource property for any given resource endpoint it is possible to **explicitly exclude fields (of media type, but also of any other type really) from default responses**:

```
people = {
    'datasource': {
        'projection': {'image': 0}
    },
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks. How can I make it so that the collection suppresses a field but viewing an individual item from the same collection includes the field?

Answer (score 2):

http://python-eve.org/features.html#leveraging-projections-to-optimize-the-handling-of-media-files

See the above suggestion in the eve docs:

```
$ curl -i http://example.com/people/<id>?projection={"image": 0}
```

Comment: Thanks. This was helpful, but I went with the other answer because it explains how to do a projection as the default for a given API endpoint.